# Stopping content that is not visible from being downloaded

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking into how to hide elements in bootstrap 3 using the hidden and visible classes but have noticed that although the content is hidden, when I reach the specified screen size it is still downloaded by the browser.

[image: Code]

I have not found anything within bootstrap that can stop content that is not displayed from being downloaded and was hoping that there was something like the [Jquery Lazy Loader Library](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) that can stop content other than images from being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will always download the images referenced by your `img` tag even if they're not visible at the moment.

If this is a problem then you need to simply not render these tags until they're needed.

This may be far outside of what's possible for you, but for completeness the knockoutJS library actually makes this easy with the `if` binding:

```
<div data-bind="if: foo">
    <img> <!-- not rendered unless foo is truthy -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about something that will keep a mobile device (as an example) from downloading unnecessary image files while keeping the page rendered flawlessly on the desktop.

*Here's what I would do.*

## [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e3p2/)

Set the example display area (bottom right frame) to less than 480px and use Chrome Network in the dev-tools or Firefox's version to see it *not* download.  Then make it bigger and re-run it and watch it show up.

### CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
    .hidden {
        display: none; /* **NOTE:** if bootstrap already does this for .hidden, maybe use opacity: 0 or max-width: 0, etc and adjust the jQuery accordingly */
    }
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var $images = $('img.hidden');
    $.each($images, function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
        }
    });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<img id="thisImage" data-src="/path/to/image.png" class="hidden">
```

---

This will essentially put a placeholder for each image that is hidden where it's supposed to go and not download it unless the browser is less than 480px (adjust to your preference of course).  Pretty common technique.

PS - if your web browser is < 480px when you load the page it will also not download.  If you want me to show you how to counteract that as well, let me know.